# How should a class that inherits from NumPy ndarray and has a default value be created?

Tags: python, arrays, inheritance, numpy, instantiation

I want to make a class that inherits from NumPy ndarray and I want to do this in such a way that I am not required to provide a value for the array on instantiation, but can have it default to something. I am having a bit of difficulty getting it working:

```
import numpy

class Variable(numpy.ndarray):

    def __init__(
        self,
        name                    = "trk_pt",
        tree                    = None, # tree object
        eventNumber             = None,
        eventWeight             = None,
        numberOfBins            = None, # binning
        binningLogicSystem      = None, # binning
        ):
        # arguments
        self._name              = name
        self.tree               = tree
        self.eventNumber        = eventNumber
        self.eventWeight        = eventWeight
        self.numberOfBins       = numberOfBins
        self.binningLogicSystem = binningLogicSystem
        # internal
        self.variableObject     = None
        self.variableType       = None
        self.dataType           = None
        self.variableDataTypes  = None
        self.canvas             = None
        self.histogram          = None
        self._values            = [] # list of values
        self._valuesRaw         = [] # list of unmodified, raw values
        # NumPy ndarray inheritance
        #self = ([1])
        if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
            super().__init__([1])
        else:
            super(numpy.ndarray, self).__init__([1])

a = Variable()
```

The error I am presented with is as follows:

```
TypeError: Required argument 'shape' (pos 1) not found
```

How do I code this such that the array has a default value on instantiation and does not require a value?

Comment: You probably want to use `__new__`, instead of `__init__`. Haven't used it in a while, though, so I'm afraid I don't remember exactly what you should do here.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html)? Subclassing ndarray is little different than regular python classes.

Comment: `super(Variable, self).__init__` is the correct v2 use of `super`.

Comment: What kinds of `array` actions do you plan doing with your new class?  Add one Variable to another Variable?  How will you set the `.tree` attribute of the new Variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this example from the docs as a guide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array), you could use

```
    self = np.asarray([1]).view(cls)
```

to instantiate the array in `__new__`:

```
import numpy as np

class Variable(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(
        cls,
        name                    = "trk_pt",
        tree                    = None, # tree object
        eventNumber             = None,
        eventWeight             = None,
        numberOfBins            = None, # binning
        binningLogicSystem      = None, # binning
        ):
        self = np.asarray([1]).view(cls)
        self._name              = name
        self.tree               = tree
        self.eventNumber        = eventNumber
        self.eventWeight        = eventWeight
        self.numberOfBins       = numberOfBins
        self.binningLogicSystem = binningLogicSystem
        ...
        return self

a = Variable()
```

---

Note also that `help(np.ndarray)` says

> No `__init__` method is needed because the array is fully
>   initialized after the `__new__` method.